# Developing a push application for different mobile platforms

Tags: web-services, mobile-website, push-notification

I must confess I am totally new to developing push services. I have to develop a REST web service (using jersey) which serves similar apps - one on Blackberry, second Android and the other Windows. I need to add push support to my service, for notifying these 3 kinds of client apps. I have been going through some blogs regarding which approach is to taken (I could google for many [alternatives](http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/) ), and it seems best to me to go for MQTT.

I cant think what method is appropriate for diverse mobile platforms, is MQTT a good choice ?

Plus, I would like to know, do the client have to be aware of the server technology used for pushing ? That is, say, if I go for implementing MQTT, would my client need to write MQTT specific code ? I would prefer a method where the client does not deal with such dependencies.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with mobile development at all, but you may be interested in the blog post that Dale Lane posted yesterday: http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=1599 He describes lots of useful things for working with MQTT on Android and provides example code.

The client will most likely be using a library for whatever push technology you look at, so any code they write would be specific to that library. I imagine you could write enough code yourself (or see from the examples above) so that the client doesn't need to worry particularly about MQTT or whichever push technology you use.